# Jupyter Notebook does not run in PyCharm

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, jupyter, jetbrains-ide

When I try to run the server when I'm using PyCharm brings me this error

[image]

> Jupyter server process exited with code 1
> usage: jupyter.py [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir] [--paths] [--json] [--debug] [subcommand]
>
> Jupyter: Interactive Computing
>
> positional arguments: subcommand the subcommand to launch
>
> optional arguments:
> -h, --help show this help message and exit
> --version show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
> --config-dir show Jupyter config dir
> --data-dir show Jupyter data dir
> --runtime-dir show Jupyter runtime dir
> --paths show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable format.
> --json output paths as machine-readable json
> --debug output debug information about paths
>
> Available subcommands: 1.0.0
>
> Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.

When running Jupyter using VSCode it works properly.

I also tried reinstalling it from PyCharm packages and terminal but still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, it could be one of known issues:
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-3920/Jupyter-cant-find-subcommand-jupyter-notebook (reproducible with WSL interpreter)
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-4066/Run-Error-when-notebook-isnt-installed (when installing jupyter-server)

If it's not applicable to your case, please submit a new issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com and provide logs from **Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data**.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue. Just open the terminal and `pip install jupyter`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not working for me in PyCharm on Mac.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't manage to solve this, but I found a workaround

1. Go to PyCharm Settings and search for Jupyter Servers
2. Open a Terminal, and start Jupyter notebook, typically:  `python3 -m notebook`
3. Copy the URL with the token to the Configured Server field in Pycharm, click OK

You should now be able to run and debug Jupyter cells in Pycharm!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I re-installed Jupyter Notebook in PyCharm terminal with:

`pip install notebook`

It solve this problem in Pycharm, I hope it works for you.

[Jupyter Notebook docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN5Jh.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not working for me in PyCharm on Mac.

Comment: This answer worked fine for me, solved my issue whoo who yippee yah hee

Answer (score 1):

I've utilized a different approach. Navigate to the folder where your **.ipynb** file is located. Start your Jupyter server, use the command **python3 -m notebook**, for instance.

[image: ref1]

Copy the URL, specifically extracting the **http://localhost:8888/tree?token=** section.

Next, open PyCharm, click on **Tools**, then select **Add Jupyter Connection**. Choose **Connect to Jupyter server using URL** and paste your URL.

[image: ref2]
[image: ref3]

You'll be prompted for the password/Token, which corresponds to the second part of the URL following **token=...**. After this step, your Jupyter server should appear in your folders.

[image: ref4]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I created my conda environment using the prompt in PyCharm. After some troubleshooting, I found that the best solution was to remove that environment and create a new one using the terminal instead. This solved the problem for me and allowed me to run Jupyter notebooks in PyCharm without any issues.

If you are experiencing the same problem, I recommend trying this solution. To create a new conda environment using the terminal, you can follow the steps outlined in the conda documentation.

I hope this helps you resolve the issue and get back to working with Jupyter notebooks in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to start jupyter via terminal with `python3 -m notebook`.

Source: [jetbrains.com/issue/DS-3120](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-3120/Pycharm-Jupyter-Jupyter-command-jupyter-notebook-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in the following way:

1. In Pycharm open the interpreter settings. Then in the list of installed packages, I removed all packages that mentioned word "jupyter"
2. Created a new file ipynb, Pycharm offered to install the jupyter package. Click install - and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in the terminal:

**python3 -m notebook**